# What factors affect propagation time for wired / wifi multicast messages?

Tags: ethernet, multicast, lan, ieee-802.11, latency

I have a newbie question on multicast delivery times.
In [this](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/osdi02/tech/full_papers/elson/elson.pdf) article on clock synchronisation they claim that the propagation time on a local network is close to zero.

What is the propagation time of multicast messages on a local ethernet network, wired or wireless?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have tried to rephrase it as a question. Ok?

Comment: I'm still voting to close because as phrased, it's way too broad.  There are zillions of different networks, all with different characteristics, depending on size, topology, type of equipment, media bandwidth, usage, etc.  Essentially, there is no answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am mainly just trying to expand the claim from the mentioned article, which claims that the propagation time on a local network (wired and wireless) is close to zero. This to me seems like a bold claim, but I do not know where to look for evidence. I am trying to test this myself, but even if I time stamp incoming packets I have the problem of each machines clock not being in perfect sync. So it is really hard to test this claim myself. NTP and PTP does not provide a strong enough synchronisation to test the claim. Any ideas?

Comment: @MikePennington you say "It depends, especially on wireless" - I guess I am looking for something like that. It depends on what? I need to multicast because I am constructing a synchronisation algorithm and I want to eliminate the senders delay (something similar to the work presented in the article).

Comment: @Mellson, RE: how to test propagation across any channel.  Ixia, Spirent, etc... all offer precision timestamping assuming you have a good clock reference for the test set.  If you want precision, you will pay for it... fortunately, you can [lease this equipment](https://www.microlease.com/us/ixia/)

Comment: @Mellson, "it depends" on [CSMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance) and the channel bit error rate (because the 802.11 data-link layer retransmits several times upon CRC errors, which effectively increases propagation time).  In the face of high channel utilization and error rates, I have literally seen wifi ping times exceed *30 seconds* to go to an AP 50 feet away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the propagation time of multicast messages on a local network, wired or wireless?

"it depends, especially on wireless", wired latency is normally in the low to mid-hundreds of microseconds range, depending on your specific switch hardware.  If there are any ethernet frames queued ahead of your traffic, latency increases based on the serialization time of those frames ahead of yours in the queue.

> ...
>
> [Mellson asked](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17493/propagation-time-for-multicast-messages?noredirect=1#comment25735_17493) @MikePennington you say "It depends, especially on wireless" - I guess I am looking for something like that. It depends on what? I need to multicast because I am constructing a synchronisation algorithm and I want to eliminate the senders delay (something similar to the work presented in the article).

Wifi latency depends on:

- [CSMA/CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance)
- wifi channel [bit error rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_error_rate) (because the 802.11 data-link layer retransmits several times upon CRC errors, which effectively increases propagation time).

In the face of high channel utilization and error rates, I have literally seen wifi ping round-trip times exceed *30 seconds* to go to an AP 50 feet away.

> [Mellson asked](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17493/propagation-time-for-multicast-messages?noredirect=1#comment25734_17493) I am mainly just trying to expand the claim from the mentioned article, which claims that the propagation time on a local network (wired and wireless) is close to zero. This to me seems like a bold claim, but I do not know where to look for evidence. I am trying to test this myself, but even if I time stamp incoming packets I have the problem of each machines clock not being in perfect sync. So it is really hard to test this claim myself. NTP and PTP does not provide a strong enough synchronisation to test the claim. Any ideas?

As for how to test propagation across any channel (wired / wifi): test equipment vendors [Ixia](http://www.ixiacom.com/), [Spirent](http://www.spirent.com/), etc... all offer precision timestamping assuming you have a good clock reference for the test set.

This equipment is expensive (and complicated).  Bottom line if you want precision, you will pay for it... fortunately, you can [lease this equipment](https://www.microlease.com/us/ixia/).  I used to do this as part of my $dayjob, but it's been quite a while and I've lost touch with capabilities and model numbers.  Call Ixia or Spirent and tell them what you are trying to do; you'll get good guidance.